# jQuery code not running

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have the code below in a document.ready, when I use Chrome's debugger to see why nothing is happening, I see that for some reason the ajax call gets skipped over?

```
var latitude = $('#LatitudeHidden').val();
                var longitude = $('#LongitudeHidden').val();
                var from = $('#<%:FromTextBox.ClientID %>').val();
                var to = $('#<%:ToTextBox.ClientID %>').val();
                var type = $('#<%:TypeEnhancedDropDownList.ClientID %>').val();
                var specialLocation = $('#<%:SpecialLocationsEnhancedDropDownList.ClientID %>').val();

                var json = {
                    'latitude': latitude,
                    'longitude': longitude,
                    'from': from,
                    'to': to,
                    'type': type, 
                    'specialLocation': specialLocation
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "List.aspx/GetFilteredLocations",
                    data: json,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    error: function(msg)
                    {
                        console.log(msg);
                    },
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        console.log(msg.d);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: @Gabe: I first used FF and there were none, then I tried Chrome and now at I looked again and there is an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Are you sure `"List.aspx/GetFilteredLocations"` is a legitimate URL?

Comment: What does the error say then?

Comment: POST http://localhost:8382/Forms/Mobile/Incidents/List.aspx/GetFilteredLocations 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.7.2.js:8240
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery-1.7.2.js:8240
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-1.7.2.js:7719
(anonymous function) List.aspx:82
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.7.2.js:1075
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.js:1193
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.7.2.js:435
DOMContentLoaded

Comment: The real error I see is:"Invalid JSON primitive: latitude.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n". Latitude does not necessarily have a value and the debugger shows the value is an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it is having trouble deserializing the json data...
You may need to stringify your data, even though you do have the datatype set to json.
There is a js library to accomplish this. [Here is JSON js library to help](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Try this (after including the JSON library into your page)

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "List.aspx/GetFilteredLocations",
     data: JSON.stringify(json),
     error: function(msg)
     {
        console.log(msg);
     },
     success: function(msg)
     {
        console.log(msg.d);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I used this library: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/. What does the stringifying do?

Comment: It takes the json object and parses it into a string notation to be passed to the server.

Comment: I had to change all my server side parameters(ints, floats etc) to strings? Now I have to cast back. Is that the only way?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: If I don't I get one of these: "{"Message":" is not a valid value for Single.","StackTrace":"   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)\